# how can i remove '}' expected error in php classes in vscode. I used these codes

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Person{
    $age;
    $firstname;
    $lastname;
    function print_name(){
    echo $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname.' is '.$this->age.' years old.';
    }
}

$person1 = new Person();
$person1->age = 17;
$person1->firstname = "Muller";
$person1->lastname = "Thimo";
$person1->print_name();
?>
```

These are the codes i used
[and these are the errors i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysav4.jpg)

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If so, please can you mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

class property should have visibility like public ,private ,protected

so it should be like

```
class Person{
    public  $age;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    function print_name(){
    echo $this->firstname.' '.$this->lastname.' is '.$this->age.' years old.';
    }
}

$person1 = new Person();
$person1->age = 17;
$person1->firstname = "Muller";
$person1->lastname = "Thimo";
$person1->print_name();
?>
```

You can read here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1):

I had '}' expected. in PHP. The problem was i had TWO Extensions installed at the same time.